# Codeigniter Remove index.php from url and add external css in the views

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi i am new to codeigniter. I tried to do the basic things but i'm getting errors. I'm using v.2.12.
I want to do two things.
1. Remove index.php 
2. Add external style sheet to my views.

I found lot of tutorial but no one is working for me. If index.php is removed then css not working. 
So can any one assist me how to do this?

I'm trying to do this basic things from the morning.

So please help me.

Thanks for reading my post

Comment: Post your codes. I.e. Rewrite rules and how you including your css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, your config page

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/t/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

your .htaccess in root folder should contain following. Make sure to change path in RewriteBase to your path.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /t/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in your views

```
<link href="<?php echo $this->config->base_url();?>css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Hope this helps